# How to shutdown local tomcat server when closing browser window?

Tags: visual-studio, tomcat, browser

I hava a web app running on a local tomcat server.

When the user starts the app (via desktop shortcut) the server starts and the app is opened in a browser window.
But when the user just clicks on the close button to stop the application the server is still running in the background - that's annoying.

I tried to utilize the "unonload" and "onbeforeunload" events from javascript but unfortunately these events are also fired on some other requests in the app. 
So I can't use them, except I do a lot of refactoring.

Does anyone have an idea for a possible solution?

Btw, what I find interesting is the behaviour of Visual Studio when debugging a web application. When I close the browser window Visual Studio also gets a trigger to stop debug mode. So it seems it somehow notices the close event of the browser window, which would be exactly what I need. But I don't know how they do it...

Comment: we had a similar request in the past, but in the end convinced the  the user to have another desktop shortcut to stop the app.

Answer (score 1):

Can you wrap the starting of Tomcat and launching your app in a batch file or shell script? (Not sure what your target OS is...)

The script/batch file would start Tomcat and then launch your application. When the user exits your application, the script/batch file would then shut down Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
The target OS is Windows and I actually start the app and the server via batch. But users normally close the app via the close button of the browser window ... and tomcat keeps running ...

Comment: OK, but can you also start the application in the same batch file as you start and stop Tomcat?

i.e. application.bat:
tomcat start


yourapp.exe


tomcat stop

Unless you do a "start yourapp.exe", running yourapp will suspend batch processing until it exits. When it does exit, tomcat should be shut down.

The key is to put all of that in a single batch file.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't come out right in the comments. In the batch file: tomcat start <newline>  yourapp.exe <newline> tomcat stop <newline>.

I can't remember the catalina command parameters to start and stop tomcat.

Comment: this sounds like a real good suggestion. Any other way is going to be a hack.

Comment: I think I'll give this suggestion a try. It sounds good. Thanks. I'll give feedback if it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a short session timeout, and use a `HttpSessionListener`. On `sessionDestroyed(..)` you can stop tomcat (using catalina.bat for example) .

Otherwise you can try to [detect browser close](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en-GB&q=javascript+detect+browser+close&sourceid=navclient-ff&rlz=1B3GGGL_en___BG265&ie=UTF-8&aq=1&oq=javascript+detect+browser), and send a shutdown message to the server using ajax (before the browser is closed).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
On some systems the app runs constantly but is only used from time to time. So when I set a short session timeout and act on sessionDestroyed(..) I'm afraid the app isn't available when the users need them. So I really have to know when the user closes the browser window.